# Multiprocessing.Pool not compiling

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

First time I use Multiprocessing package. I want to compute a ML function several times (with different input).

I have tried the following, where series is the iterable and fbp_prediction is a function that returns a list:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm

p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
predictions = list(tqdm(p.imap(fbp_prediction, series), total=len(series)))
p.close()
p.join()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

When it's run, appears that the process remains at 0% (tqdm output). After waiting for a "long" time, its seems like the program runs infinitely and never returns an output.

Could anyone explain me why and how you would fix it?

Comment: You didn't start anything. Read [multiprocessing - examples Using Pool:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#examples)